# SharePoint List View - Group by user

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, list-view, view

I'm trying to create some views on a list of contracts, one of the views that have been requested is 'group by consultant'.

The consultant field is just a standard SharePoint 'Person or Group' field however when I open the list of fields to sort in the 'Group by' option then consultant isn't listed - presumably because SharePoint doesn't allow grouping on this field type?

Is there anyway to enable grouping on a person/group field or is this not possible?

Answer (score 2):

that's weird, you should have no problem with group by that type of fields as I show in the picture below
[image]

As you can see Im filtering by a custom field called friends.
Could you tell me how you created the field?, Could you upload an image of the field, like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for the response. Other than multiple selections my field settings were identical. I've tested it on an older list and disabling multiple selections allows you to group by the field. In hindsight this makes sense really.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the "consultant field" is set to use People and not Groups, also make sure that the "allow multiple selections" area of the people picker field is set to "no". SharePoint lists can only group by unique values. If you have it set to multiple selections is will be unable to read the users who are the "consultants" (in your case).

Hope this helps.